# Want to upgrade the zookeeper from 3.4.14 to 3.5.6 /latest

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Want to upgrade the zookeeper from 3.4.14 to recent/3.5.6. I have followed the [link](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.3-beta/zookeeperReconfig.html#sc_reconfig_clientport) for upgrade and downloaded the zookeeper [jar](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper/3.5.6/source-code).
but still on restarting server, it is failing in loading the data.
Tried with snapshot.trust.empty=true flag in configuration but in this case it is not able to load the previous data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked by adding snapshot.0 file in version directory in zookeeper data directory.